# Visual Studio Code - Python interactive data science REPL with autocomplete

Tags: python, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Since VS Code supports JupyterNotebooks natively with the Python extension (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) I like to launch the notebooks and see the outputs directly in VS Code.

The only issue I'm having with this is that the `Python Interactive` window is not that interactive, it just works to show the output of the cells.

Is there any way to allow autocomplete functionality in that console? Something more like an `IPython` console where I can hit `Tab` and see all the available options.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that this currently does not exist. The input box on the Interactive Windows is basically just a plain text input terminal (with colorization) currently. We do have a work item to track adding autocomplete here. If you want to watch or upvote that item it's located here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4170